# No Topic matches the given query

Tags: python, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVuk3.png)I'm learning Chapter 18 18.4.3 in Python Crash Course,when i open http://localhost:8000/topics/1 ,I get this problem-No Topic matches the given query. Django 3.0.7 and python 3.8

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Topic


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topics.html',context)
def topic(request,topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic,id=topic_id)
    entries = Topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context={'topic':topic},{'entries':entries}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('topics/',views.topics,name='topics'),
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

topics.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <p>Topics</p>
  <ul>
      {% for topic in topics %}
        <li>{{ topic }}</li>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'topic' topic_id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
        </li>
      {% empty %}
        <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

topic.html

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}
{% block header %}
  <h2>{{ topic }}</h2>
{% endblock header %}
{% block content %}
  <p>Entries:</p>
   <ul>
       {% for entry in entries %}
         <li>
             <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
             <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
         </li>
      {% empty %}
      <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass multiple items to the template, you should pass it in *one* dictionary, so:

```
def topic(request,topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic,id=topic_id)
    entries = Topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic':topic, 'entries':entries}
    return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)
```

By writing <s>`context={'topic':topic},{'entries':entries}`</s>, you constructed a 2-tuple that contains two dictionaries.

In the template, you furthermore should use the `.id` attribute of `topic:

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
```

Note that the database needs to contain a `Topic` object with the given id (here `1`). If that is not the case, then of course the page can not render details of a non-existing `Topic`.

Comment: I change it to this ,but I get the same result.

Comment: Not Found: /topics/1/
[26/Jun/2020 06:32:59] "GET /topics/1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1733

Comment: @dkemf: are you sure there *is* a topic in the database with this id?

Comment: yes ,I will upload a topic .html.wait a little later.

Comment: @dkemf: this is not stored in a template, but in the *database*.